# Target Blank code in li and echo

Tags: php

I am using the following code, need to apply target blank during the link.

`echo "<li><a href=showBest.html?title=".$row['fld_url'].">".substr($row['fld_caption'],0,90)."</a></li>";`

Where is the `target=\"_blank\""` need to apply to make it worked out? Any help where to put that target blank code? I am not able to figuring it out nice.

Comment: you have unnecessary " at end of 'target=\"_blank\""'

Comment: possible duplicate of [Target Blank in PhP echo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13448645/target-blank-in-php-echo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo "<li><a target='_blank' href=showBest.html?title=".$row['fld_url'].">".substr($row['fld_caption'],0,90)."</a></li>";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "<li><a href=\"showBest.html?title=".$row['fld_url']."\" target=\"_blank\">".substr($row['fld_caption'],0,90)."</a></li>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put it into a "a tag"

```
echo "<li><a target='_blank' href=showBest.html?title=".$row['fld_url'].">".substr($row['fld_caption'],0,90)."</a></li>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use This one

```
 <?php echo "<li><a target='_blank'   href=showBest.html?title=".$row['fld_url'].">".substr($row['fld_caption'],0,90)."</a></li>";
?>
```

This may helpful to you!!!!